# How to model accepting a pdf file as input in VDM++

Tags: file, input, vdm++

Let say I want to model a program that will accept a file of type `pdf`.

How should I model accepting a `pdf` file as input in VDM++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model how something processes a PDF file, in principle. But then the problem becomes one of how to represent the structure of a PDF in VDM. You would then specify what functions or operations the program would perform on that data. Are you really asking about how to represent a PDF file structure in VDM?

Comment: Not just pdf, but any kind of file. I’ve never seen specification that models accepting file as input

Comment: If it's a specification of how to process the file data, rather than a spec that *reads* a file as part of its functionality, then it would not look like it was accepting a file input. It might be a function that accepts a mk_PDF record value (say) that represents the file. It is possible to literally read a file using the IO`freadval library, but the value in the file is still a VDM value that represents something.